# Redis property pubsub instead of keyspace

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I know we can do a pubsub to, for example, `__keyspace@0__:foo` to subscribe to changes on foo.  I am wondering if there is a way to subscribe to changes on a shared property of any key, for example, changes to `*.value` so we get notified anytime a value field is changed, regardless of the key...does anyone know off the top of their head?  I'm having a hard time finding information.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to just be notified when **any** value changes? If so just replace your key name with `*`, e.g.

```
$ redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__key*__:*'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That's what we're doing now, but we're looking for a way to get notified when the field called "value" changes on any key.  I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: What do you mean by "field"? Are you talking about hashes?

Comment: For example, if I 'HSET this.hash field1 30', I'd like to be notified that field1 was set to 30 by someone on this.hash, regardless of whether I am watching it directly.  But I don't really care about other fields...not a big problem, just looking to see if a way to streamline this process exists.  Fairly new to Redis.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but you can use the config to only listen for hash events, but you would have to filter the hash events you're interested in in your application code